# Divisibility of a number $N$ by $4,7,9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Let $$N=\binom{20}{7}-\binom{20}{8}+\binom{20}{9}-\binom{20}{10}+\binom{20}{11}-\binom{20}{12}+.......-\binom{20}{20}.$$
>
> Then $N$ is divisible by
>
> $\bf{Options::}\;\;:: (a)\; 4\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\; 7\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\;\; 9\;\;\;\;\;\; (d)\;\; None\; of\;  these.$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using $$(1+x)^n = \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}x+\binom{n}{2}x^2+..........+\binom{n}{n}x^n.$$

Now put $x=-1\;,n=20\;,$ We get $$0=\binom{20}{0}-\binom{20}{1}+\binom{20}{2}+.......+\binom{20}{20}=S$$

So we get $$-N=-\binom{20}{7}+\binom{20}{8}-\binom{20}{9}+\binom{20}{10}-\binom{20}{11}+\binom{20}{12}+.......+\binom{20}{20}$$

So $$-N = S-\binom{20}{0}+\binom{20}{1}-\binom{20}{2}+\binom{20}{3}-\binom{20}{4}+\binom{20}{5}-\binom{20}{6}$$

So we get $$N=\binom{20}{0}-\binom{20}{1}+\binom{20}{2}-\binom{20}{3}+\binom{20}{4}-\binom{20}{5}+\binom{20}{6}$$

So we get $$N=1-20+\frac{20\cdot 19}{2}-\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot 18}{3\cdot 2}+\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot 18 \cdot 17 }{4\cdot 3\cdot 2}-\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16}{ 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2}+\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16\cdot 15}{ 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2}$$

Now How can I proceed after that.

or If there is any short method then plz explain here.

Thanks

Comment: See [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem).

Comment: @Lucian: Lucas's theorem works for checking the divisibility of one binomial coefficient by a prime number. But $4$ and $9$ are not primes, and the problem uses multiple binomial coefficients that could cancel each other out. How could Lucas's theorem be useful here?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: No, but they are prime powers, so perhaps the related [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem) might be of some assistance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You began as I would have. If you have a calculator, you can just find the value of $N$ directly. If you don't have a calculator or you want to avoid such calculations, you can proceed using only modular arithmetic, which is easy enough to do without a calculator.

Each fraction in your last formula for $N$ is an integer, of course. You can strike out common factors from the numerators and denominators, then simplify the calculation by using only modular arithmetic. To check the divisibility by $4$, use modulo $4$.

$$\begin{align}
N\ &\equiv (1) - (20) + (10\cdot 19) - (20\cdot 19\cdot 3) + (5\cdot 19\cdot 3\cdot 17) - (19\cdot 3\cdot 17\cdot 16) + (19\cdot 17\cdot 8\cdot 15)\\
 &\equiv (1)-(0)+(2\cdot -1)-(0\cdot 19\cdot 3)+(1\cdot -1\cdot -1\cdot 1)-(19\cdot 3\cdot 17\cdot 0)+(19\cdot 17\cdot 0\cdot 15) \\
 &\equiv 1-0+-2-0+1-0+0 \\
 &\equiv 0 \pmod 4
\end{align}$$

We conclude that $N$ is divisible by $4$.

Redo that modulo $7$ and $9$ to get your final answer. I get that $N$ is also divisible by $7$ but not by $9$. It seems your final answer should be both choices $(a)$ and $(b)$. Can your test/homework handle that?